# Gem:load error while creating new app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport

While creating the new app in rails by rails new projectname Iam getting this error i googled a lot but cant find the solution.

```
     /home/aaquib/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb
    :2274:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate activesupport-
     5.1.2, 
    already activated activesupport-5.0.5 (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: Remove the activesupport-5.0.5 and run bundle. What do you get?

Comment: i removed the entire gem by clean gem command and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problem is solved ..IAm posting the answer for others .
just add this in terminal..

```
  gem clean
```

and then create a new app by rails new projectname.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this by removing your `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install` again. You have two conflicting versions of the same gem locked at the same time, which leads to this error.

If that alone doesn't work, try also running `spring stop` to start with a clean slate.

Comment: i cleaned up my gems by clean gem and i think its working now .but is der any problem in doing so means will it affect my other rails app?

Comment: @AaquibKhan try deleting the gemsets that give you an issue by doing `rbenv gemset list` and then `rbenv gemset delete XXX`.